# Synonimise [alpha] and [transparency]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, burnination

There are [31 questions](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpha?sort=votes&pageSize=50) tagged with the [alpha](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpha) tag, a lot of which are also tagged [transparency](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transparency). Most of these are basic questions about transparency, with only a few about advanced manipulation of alpha channels. The tag [alpha](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpha) does not have an explanation.

I vote to make [alpha](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpha) a synonym of [transparency](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transparency) and add a mention about alpha channels in the transparency description.

---

I will add two answers to guide the voting process. Upvote the one you agree with. *There is no need to downvote an answer.*

Comment: First opacity, now alpha... boy you really like your tags clear :)

Comment: yes, I have a burning hatred for useless tags :D

Comment: Where is your third answer?

Comment: Aha, right, I decided 'kinda' was unnecessary.

Comment: Agreed, *kinda* just makes things more complicated.

Comment: And I think you mean a 'burninating' hatred :P

Comment: lolz, exactly :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## YES

[alpha](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpha) and [transparency](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transparency) are basically the same thing and should be tag synonyms. The tag with the fewest questions should be made obsolete.

Comment: OK, seems clear. I'll clean up the tags and let it be known when I'm done so a mod can make the synonyms.

Comment: Done, the alpha tag is no longer. Could a mod create the synonyms? And maybe edit the transparency tag description to include alpha channel manipulation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## NO.

[alpha](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpha) and [transparency](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transparency) do *not* mean the same thing. There is a clear added value in keeping both and adding an explanation to [alpha](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpha).